# @MockBean vs @Autowired intermittently leading to test failures when used in two separate testing classes for the same bean

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I'm facing this weird issue of testing methods failing due to apparent dirty beans in the context.

I have, for example a testing class like this:

**EDIT:** I removed the @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) as it was added by mistake. This code is dumbed down to hide business aspects and the original code doesn't include this annotation either.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
class FirstScenarioTest extends BaseRedisTest {

     @MockBean
     private Service service;

     @Autowired
     private Controller controller;

     void testScenario1Works() {
         final var generatedValue = "expectedValue";
         when(service.methodThatReturnsSomething()).thenReturn(generatedValue);
         Assertions.assertEquals(generatedValue, controller.makeUseOfService());
     }
}
```

And then another testing class like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
class SecondScenarioTest extends BaseRedisTest {

     @Autowired
     private Service service;


     void testScenario2Works() {
         Assertions.assertEquals("expectedResult", service.methodThatReturnsSomething());
     }
}
```

In a scenario like this, my tests are intermittently failing due to sometimes Service returning null. (possibly because the @Autowired attribute still gets a mockBean version?)

Then I use `@DirtiesContext` in both classes and it starts working for all tests, or also when I change the `@Order` to force the `@Autowired` service to run before the `@MockBean` one.

Any idea of any JUnit or Mockito resource that would fix this without having to order or use dirties context?

P.S. I tried to do a `Mockito.reset(service)` on an `@AfterEach` method and it didn't work.

Comment: Both tests, as you mentioned them here, will use a fresh application context. So they shouldn't influence each other, unless there is something in here you aren't showing (and judging from what is here this is a dumbed down version of the actual code). I also don't get why you have `@RunWith` as it appears you are using JUnit5 and not JUnit4 (judging from the access modifiers of the class and your supposed test method). That being said for the controller you should favor `@WebMvcTest` over `@SpringBootTest` it will be faster as it will only construct the necessary beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the note on `@RunWith`. I edited and removed.
The other thing that is hidden from this code is the fact I'm using Testcontainers to bootstrap some servers such as Redis and Kafka. I've been wondering if it could be something related to testcontainers influencing the natural behavior of junit. For that reason also I'm not using `@WebMvcTest`. The actual bootstrap is more complex and depends on more than what I'm exposing here.

Comment: If there is more you will need to expose is. At what is shown here shouldn't display what you are experiencing as both will operate on different contexts. For the controller test you don't need test containers as you are mocking the dependencies (at least what you show here) so you don't need the base class only a mock and the controller. Which could actually be the culprit as both will also start a container in test containers which might lead to 1 being shutdown.